# Change retention time on prometheus

Tags: ubuntu, prometheus, grafana

So I am running Prometheus on an Ubuntu server and started running it a while ago by just running

```
sudo ./prometheus
```

However, I wanted to append

```
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y
```

to the end of this command. How can I change the storage retention time of a running Prometheus process without stopping Prometheus from collecting metrics. It is very import that I change the retention time WITHOUT losing the metrics that Prometheus has already collected on this server. Please let me know anything that might help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
if you use the docker container
[image]

```
docker run  -p 9090:9090 -itd --name prometheus  \ 
-v /prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  prom/prometheus \
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

VM environment
[image]

```
prometheus  --storage.tsdb.retention.time=2y --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```